# Laravel 4 route protected pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a controller `UserController.php` which contains the following methods:
getIndex(), getAll(), getCreate(), postStore(), getShow(), getEdit(), putUpdate(), getDestroy(), getLogin(), getDashboard(), and getLogout().

I have included the following codes into the routes.php

```
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
    return View::make('hello');
    });
    Route::get('users/all/', [ 'as' => 'users.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@getAll']);
    Route::get('users/create/', [ 'as' => 'users.getCreate', 'uses' => 'UserController@getCreate']);
    Route::get('users/{all}/edit', 'UserController@getEdit');
    Route::put('users/update/{id}', [ 'as' => 'users.putUpdate', 'uses' => 'UserController@putUpdate']);
    Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

I can access the pages like

```
http://localhost/testlaravell/users/
```

or

```
http://localhost/testlaravell/users/add
```

etc.

Now, I want that only logged in users can access the pages, other wise s/he will be redirect to the login page http://localhost/testlaravell/login

The methods for login under `UserController.php` as follows:

```
public function postSignin() {

        $rules = array(
        'username'    => 'required', // make sure the username is an actual username
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
        );

        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('users/login')
        ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
        ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form

        } else {

        // create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
        'username'     => Input::get('username'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {


         return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', 'Welcome User');

        } else {        

        // validation not successful, send back to form 
        return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', 'Sorry!! Username/ Password seems wrong.');

          }

     }       
 }

public function getLogin() {
    return View::make('users.login');
    }
```

Comment: With the code you've posted isn't your login page http://localhost/testlaravell/users/login not http://localhost/testlaravell/login I can't see a route that would result in the login without the users being part of the route.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make use of the Auth Filter in Laravel 4

You can wrap all your routes in a group and specify that filter, in your case the code would be something like this.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('users/all/', [ 'as' => 'users.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@getAll']);
    Route::get('users/create/', [ 'as' => 'users.getCreate', 'uses' => 'UserController@getCreate']);
    Route::get('users/{all}/edit', 'UserController@getEdit');
    Route::put('users/update/{id}', [ 'as' => 'users.putUpdate', 'uses' => 'UserController@putUpdate']);
    Route::controller('users', 'UserController'); 
});
```

You can checkout the documentation on Route Groups [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups)

Comment: When I added the code you suggested above, it shows - "This web page has a redirect loop".

Comment: Can you post your entire `routes.php` something must be causing the loop. Also could be good if you can use the inspector in the browser to see what its redirecting to when you try and access the page as an unauthorized user.

Comment: Please check above for the edited code under routes.php

Comment: I see that page went to login while accessing the dashboard page, however, this show as - "This web page has a redirect loop"

Comment: I assume your login page works already? In Laravel 5 you have to bind the auth Route I forget how this works in 4.

Comment: Yes. I have modified my question with the methods that I have implemented for login purpose. Please check.